# Extra User Register Information can't store in database such as phoneno playergameid exclude username,password in django while using Usercreationform

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3i2r.png)
I am a beginner for django. I have just finished my django course. So I want to develop mini project. In that project I want to store user register informations in model database table. But I can store only username and password while using UserCreationForm. But I want to store extra and all informations in my django model database table. Please help me to solve this.

models.py

````py
    from django.db import models
    class Playerinfo(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=24)
        pubg_name= models.CharField(max_length=14)
        pubg_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        email_id = models.EmailField()
        phone_no = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        password1 = models.CharField(max_length=16)
        password2 = models.CharField(max_length=16)```
````

forms.py

```py
    from bgmiapp.models import Playerinfo
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.forms import fields
    from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput
    class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
        username = forms.CharField(max_length=24)
        pubg_name= forms.CharField(max_length=14)
        pubg_id = forms.IntegerField()
        email_id = forms.EmailField()
        phone_no = forms.IntegerField()
        password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=16,widget=PasswordInput)
        password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=16,widget=PasswordInput)
        class Meta():
            model = User
            fields = ('username','pubg_name','pubg_id','email_id','phone_no','password1','password2')
```

views.py

````py
    from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
    from .forms import RegisterForm
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
    # Create your views here.
    def register(request):
        form=RegisterForm()
        if request.method =='POST':
            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                raw_password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user=authenticate(username=username,password=raw_password)
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            form=RegisterForm()
        return render(request,'bgmiapp/register.html',{'form':form})```
````

urls.py

```py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from bgmiapp import views
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    
   

    urlpatterns = [
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
            path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
            path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='bgmiapp/login.html'),name='login'),
            path('accounts/profile/',views.profile,name='profile'),
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

in forms.py, you used:

```
class Meta():
    model = User
```

while your informations do not come from User model but Playerinfo model, the solution would be to change it to:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

- instead of rewriting all field the form will get them directly from your model
- instead of writing all the fields use **all** method

but the ideal use, would be to leave User as it is, and have a one-to-one relation

```
class Playerinfo(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  pubg_name= models.CharField(max_length=14)
  pubg_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  email_id = models.EmailField()
  phone_no = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Comment: here is a good article/tutorial on how you can proceed with this, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: In form.py RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta():
    model = Profile
    fields = '__all__